# matching regex using grep in perl

Tags: perl, grep

I am using grep inside my perl script with backticks.

```
grep -r --include=*.txt -e '[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]*$' $dir -n >> test.txt;
```

I am trying to filter out lines that ends with a filename.

Example:
file1.txt contains:

```
This is a file about file.txt
This file is about algorithms. 
File.txtbis contains several functions.
There are also several files. 
One of the files is sample.c
Another example is test.doc
```

I expect my grep to return the following lines:

```
This is a file about file.txt
One of the files is sample.c
Another example is test.doc
```

But my grep command does not return anything.

If I removed the "$" sign, the grep command, returns ALL the line of the file even though it did not match the regex.

Also, I would prefer to filter out 1 or more characters, instead of 0 or more, but grep only have *. Can I use "+" in grep for 1 or more character?

Is there a limitation in using grep in backticks?

Comment: `filter out lines that ends with a filename` - what do you mean? Extension? Any extension?

Comment: I have updated the description. I am referring to any extension names.

Comment: Modify your `-e` to `-P` or `-E` in alternative.

Comment: Try `grep -Er --include=*.txt -e '[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z]+$' $dir -n >> test.txt;`

Comment: Use `File::Find` or `File::Find::Rule` instead of running `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use File::Find qw( find );

# use File::Slurper qw( read_lines );

sub read_lines {
    my $file_name = shift;
    open my $fh, "<", $file_name or die "Couldn't open $file_name: $!";
    my @buf = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    chomp @buf;
    return @buf;
}

find(
    {
        no_chdir => 1,
        wanted   => sub {
            my $file_path = $File::Find::name;
            next unless -f $file_path;
            my $file_name = $file_path;
            $file_name =~ s/^.*\///;    # drop everything until last '/'

            for ( read_lines($file_path) ) {
                print "$_\n" if m/\Q$file_name\E\s*$/;
            }
        },
    },
    '.'
);
```

If you need to refer to other files, simply accumulate file names before lookup like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use File::Find qw( find );

# use File::Slurper qw( read_lines );

sub read_lines {
    my $file_name = shift;
    open my $fh, "<", $file_name or die "Couldn't open $file_name: $!";
    my @buf = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    chomp @buf;
    return @buf;
}

my @file_paths = ();

find(
    {
        no_chdir => 1,
        wanted   => sub {
            my $file_path = $File::Find::name;
            next unless -f $file_path;
            push @file_paths, $file_path;
        },
    },
    '.'
);

my @file_names = map {
    my $file_name = $_;
    $file_name =~ s/^.*\///;    # drop everything until last '/'
    $file_name;
} @file_paths;

my $regexp = '(?:' . join( '|', map { "\Q$_\E" } @file_names ) . ')$';
$regexp = qr/$regexp/;

for my $file_path (@file_paths) {
    for ( read_lines($file_path) ) {
        print "$_\n" if /$regexp/;
    }
}
```

Comment: @chris-yo, If this helped, please mark it as accepted by pressing the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

grep -Er --include=*.txt -e '[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+$' $dir -n >> test.txt;